# symmetric simple random walk: P(Si≥0 for all 1≤i≤2n | S2n=0)

Tags: random-walk

**The question is**
$\mathbb{P}$($X_{i}$ =1)=$\mathbb{P}$($X_{i}$ = -1)=1/2 for all 1≤i≤2n. 
For every 1≤i≤2n, Define $S_{i}$=$X_{1}$+$X_{2}$+...$X_{i}$.
What is the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}$($S_{i}$≥0 for all 1≤i≤2n | $S_{2n}$=0)?

And **my thought** is

$\mathbb{P}$($S_{i}$≥0 for all 1≤i≤2n | $S_{2n}$=0)=$\frac{\mathbb{P}(S_{i}≥0 for all 1≤i≤2n ,S_{2n}=0)}{\mathbb{P}(S_{2n}=0)}$=
$\frac{\mathbb{P}(S_{2n}=0|S_{i}≥0 for all 1≤i≤2n)*\mathbb{P}(S_{i}≥0 for all 1≤i≤2n)}{\mathbb{P}(S_{2n}=0)}$=$\frac{\mathbb{P}(S_{2n}=0|S_{2n-1}≥0)*\mathbb{P}(S_{i}≥0 for all 1≤i≤2n)}{\mathbb{P}(S_{2n}=0)}$

And **my problem** is:  I don't know wheather [$\mathbb{P}(S_{2n}=0|S_{i}≥0 for all 1≤i≤2n)$=$\mathbb{P}(S_{2n}=0|S_{2n-1}≥0)$] is correct? Also I don't know how to solve $\mathbb{P}(S_{i}≥0 for all 1≤i≤2n)$.

Comment: Please don't use generic terms like "question" in the title. All posts on this site are questions – imagine how the main page would look and how inefficient it would be if everyone did that.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: @joriki Okay, thanks for reminding